# How to make JavaScript object from the given json string

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a large json data that I have to parse and get object out of the following Json string. I added just top part of that large json data. I tried to parse it by

```
let obj = JSON.parse(this.state.data);
```

it doesn't work, it breaks with this msg "SyntaxError: Unexpected token L in JSON at position 0".

If I get the console.log by `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2));` and try to validate output by online JSON validator, it says it is valid JSON data. Could you please tell me how can I parse it?

```
{
"content": [
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "Warehouse A",
  "location": {
    "lat": 47.13111,
    "long": -61.54801
  },
  "cars": {
    "location": "West wing",
    "vehicles": [
      {
        "model": "GX",
        "price": 27395.26,
        "licensed": false,
        "_id": 15,
        "make": "Lexus",
        "year_model": 2005,
        "date_added": "2017-11-12T00:00:00.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "model": "Q",
        "price": 6103.4,
        "licensed": false,
        "_id": 9,
        "make": "Infiniti",
        "year_model": 1995,
        "date_added": "2017-11-13T00:00:00.000+00:00"
      },
     .........xxxxxx continue
```

Comment: If `JSON.stringify(this.state.data, null, 2)` logs an unnecessarily formatted object, then `this.state.data` is not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), so why try to parse it as such?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `this.state.data` is not a JSON. It's a Javascript Object, just like JSON, So, Why not just use `let obj = this.state.data;`

Comment: In my reactjs app I have to display each of those data in systematic manner. To do this I have to build object out the the json string that I get from the backend.

Comment: _"It's a Javascript Object, just like JSON"_ - O.o

Comment: I am new in Javascript world, I am thinking it in Java way. So how do you suggest to display all those date, lets say in table.